# Quarkus-resteasy-multipart could not find writer for content-type multipart/form-data type

Tags: java, resteasy, quarkus-rest-client

I am working on a project on which server-side I have used REST service for my APIS. If I use the REST service in the main function of a class, it is working fine. But when I calling it from a servlet that using Quarkus-resteasy, it throws exceptions.  The exceptions are as follows.

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type multipart/form-data type: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataOutput
```

The main code of the servlet is as follows.

```
    String httpURL = "REST api";
    String filePath = "filePath";
    ResteasyClient resteasyClient = null;
    ResteasyWebTarget resteasyWebTarget = null;
    MultipartFormDataOutput multipartFormDataOutput = null;
    GenericEntity<MultipartFormDataOutput> genericEntity = null;
    Response response = null;

    try{
        resteasyClient = new ResteasyClientBuilderImpl().build();
        resteasyWebTarget = resteasyClient.target(httpURL);
        resteasyWebTarget.property("Content-Type", MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        multipartFormDataOutput = new MultipartFormDataOutput();
        multipartFormDataOutput.addFormData(
                "file",
                new FileInputStream(filePath),
                MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE,
                "fileName");
        genericEntity = new GenericEntity<MultipartFormDataOutput>(multipartFormDataOutput, MultipartFormDataOutput.class);

        // invoke service
        response = resteasyWebTarget
                       .request()
                       .post(Entity.entity(genericEntity, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA));
```

The dependencies of the project are as follows.

```
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-client-jackson'
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-client'
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-multipart'
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy'
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jackson'
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-arc'
testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5'
testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured'
```

The strange thing is that the same code in the main function of the class can run well. I have been troubled by this problem for a day, I would be grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Quarkus messed up Provider discovery. If you add it manually, the writer can be found. e.g.:

```
@Provider
@Produces({"multipart/form-data"})
public class MultiformWriterProvider extends MultipartFormDataWriter{}
```